# Suboptimal convergence in PyTorch compared to TensorFlow when using Adam optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

My program for training a model in PyTorch converges worse than the TensorFlow implementation. When I switch to SGD instead of Adam, the losses are identical. With Adam, the losses are different starting at the very first epoch. I believe I'm using the same settings in both programs. Any thoughts on how to debug this would be helpful!

**Losses using SGD**

PyTorch

```
0.1504615843296051
0.10858417302370071
0.08603279292583466
```

TensorFlow

```
0.15046157
0.108584
0.08603277
```

**Losses using Adam**

PyTorch

```
0.0031117501202970743
0.0020642257295548916
0.0019268309697508812
0.0016333406092599034
0.0017334128497168422
0.0014430736191570759
0.0010424457723274827
0.0012145100627094507
0.0011195113183930516
0.0009501167223788798
0.0009987876983359456
0.0007953296881169081
0.00075263757025823
0.0008374055614694953
0.000735406531020999
```

TensorFlow:

```
0.0036667113
0.0032563617
0.0021536187
0.0015266595
0.0013580231
0.0013878695
0.0011856346
0.0011136091
0.00091276
0.000890126
0.00088381825
0.0007283067
0.00081382995
0.0006670901
0.00046282331
```

**Adam optimizer settings**

TF 1.15.3:

```
adam_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=5e-5)

# default parameters from the documentation at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.0/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L32-L235:
# learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8, use_locking=False, name="Adam")
```

PyTorch

```
torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=5e-5, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=0.0)
```

**Training**

- I loaded identical weights from file to initialize the two models.
- I trained and tested on a single data sample, also loaded from file. I used 1000 iterations for training and 1 for test, batch size 1.

**Prior debugging**

- As above, I used identical parameters and data
- I ran a single forward-backward pass using the Adam optimizer and saved the data and gradients at each layer. I plotted the results. All looked the same and were within 1e-6 to 1e-10 of each other. The loss was also identical within rounding error.

**Saving and loading the PyTorch model**

```
def train(...):
    ...
    checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_file, map_location=device)
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
    ...
    counter = 0
    while run:
            counter += 1
            if counter > 1000:
                break

            in = np.load("debug_data/in.npy")
            out1 = np.load("debug_data/out1.npy")
            out2 = np.load("debug_data/out2.npy")

            # adjust from TF
            in = in.squeeze(3)
            in = np.expand_dims(in, axis=0)
            ... do the same for out1 and out2

        in, out1, out2 = \
                torch.from_numpy(in).to(device), \
                torch.from_numpy(out1).to(device), \
                torch.from_numpy(out2).to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out1_hat, out2_hat = model(in)

        train_loss = loss_fn(out1_hat, out1) + loss_fn(out2_hat, out2)
        train_loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

    save_checkpoint({'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
                    'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()},
                    latest_filename=latest_checkpoint_path)
```

**Saving and loading the TensorFlow model**

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(my_path, graph=sess.graph)

restorer = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V2)
restorer.restore(sess, load_path)

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V2)

counter = 0
while run:
    counter += 1
    if counter > 1000:
        break

    in = np.load("")
    out1 = np.load("")
    out2 = np.load("")
    out1 = out1[0, :, :, :]
    out1 = out1[:, :, :, np.newaxis]
    out2 = out2[0, :, :, :]
    out2 = out2[:, :, :, np.newaxis]
    in = in[0, :, :, :]
    in = in[:, :, :, np.newaxis]
    _, _loss = sess.run([optimizer, loss],
    feed_dict={in: in, out1: out1, out2: out2})

save_path = saver.save(sess, my_save_path, global_step=int(_global_step))

sess.close()
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on this issue? I'm seeing similar issues where I'm getting much worse convergence training a pytorch model compared to a tensorflow model even though their outputs on the forward pass are equivalent (give or take rounding error)

Comment: Sadly, no progress yet!

Comment: There is a library called [ivy](https://github.com/unifyai/ivy) which allows you to implement one algorithm to switch backends (torch/tensorlow) for computation. Maybe its worth trying to see if the issue persists if you can write the same exact code but switch backends?

Answer (score 0):

The default epsilon in TF is 1e-7 not 1e-8. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.13.1/keras/optimizers/adam.py).